# linear searches in 2d arrays

Tags: c

```
    #define NUMLEG 7 

    int Search_type(char leg_type[6][10], int travel_int[6][15], int trip_num);


             c = Search_type(type,leg_type, travel_int, trip_num);
                  if (c  == -1)
                    printf("Destination not found.\n");
                  else
                    printf("Destination Found \nDestination Name:%s", travel_name[c]);


    int Search_type( char type, char leg_type[6][10], int travel_int[6][15], int trip_num)
    {
      int i, n;
      char target;
      getchar();
      printf("Please enter travel type you wish to search by:");
      scanf("%c", &target);
      for (i =0; i <trip_num; i++)
        {
          for ( n = 0; n < travel_int[i][NUMLEG]; n++)
            {
              if( leg_type[i][n] == target)
                {
                  return i;
                }
            }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

This is a rip out of a function I'm currently working on from a project and for some strange reason I can't seem to get it to search properly, I know that its not the rest of the code but this area since all the other function works properly. So I decided to break this out of the code and test it.

I can't seem to get it to search after 1 row:

travel_int[i][NUMLEG] contains the number of legs 
leg_type is where i store the char of each leg

I want it to search through the leg_type till it finds the specified character. Without pointers.

**EDIT**

For example
Trip#:1 
Destination Name:Austin 
Leg(#1):A 
Leg(#2):T

Trip#:2 
Destination Name:Florida 
Leg(#1):S 
Leg(#2):F

so

trip number = 2

travel_int stores 2 trips and each trip has 2 legs

leg type stores in the 2 leg types at the trip number

When I put in A or T it prints out Austin like it should but when I input S or F it return destination not found =/. Am I doing the search wrong, or is it the print statement that is wrong. Or is it where I'm place my return -1;. 
(I would put up the code but its a bit long..)

Comment: nothing can be interpreted from explnation or code .Please describe what these arrays are holding and what you want tosearch and what is this target containing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nested loops you are **returning -1** without doing **complete search in the entire arrays**.

**Place return -1 outside all the for() loops.**

```
   for (i =0; i <trip_num; i++)
    {
      for ( n = 0; n < travel_int[i][NUMLEG]; n++)
        {
          if( leg_type[i][n] == target)
            {
              return i;
              break;
            }
        }

}   return -1
```

This would definitely make your **program run correctly**.And this is the only reason why you get the correct results when you search for trip #01.